# git: blob's file not recoverable and blob corrupt -> need get rid of blob

Tags: git, blob

Sorry in advance for any inconvenience, repetition, confusion, misunderstanding, impoliteness, my bad english, whatever. I assume this post might have something wrong which I don't see, because it is my mistake. I tried reasonably to solve it myself.

**This is my question:**

1. How to completely get rid of a broken blob in a previous commit,
   or,
2. how to "revert" to a previous commit as if the commit never had happened.
   The latter case means, going back to the state of the git-DB (the .git folder)
   where the blob in question was not created.

**This is my problem:**
On the git repo of my project, I have a blob in a previous commit that is corrupted.
Checking it, I found that the assigned file of the blob is missing.
I can not, in no way, recover the file in that state, it is lost forever.
(Not really a problem, I still have the file in the state before and after the commit which introduced the broken blob)
So I can't do a
`git hash-object ....`
as described here:
http://web.mit.edu/git/www/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.html
simply because I can't create the exact blob/hash because I don't have the file in that state.

Try to "circumvent" this also failed:
I tried git reset --hard HEAD~1, cherry pick, rebase, branch, revert etc.
but in any case the broken blob persists to be there.
I need to COMPLETELY ERASE that broken blob from the GIT DB (.git folder).
If I could go back to the commit before that broken blob was introduced, and so make it disappear, I could fix up things manually.

I haven't push any of this to remote yet, so I only have this problem locally.

Comment: does `git reset <sha of correct commit>` also fail ?

Comment: also : is that corrupt blob part of one single commit only (e.g : was it modified right after it was introduced) ? or do several commits point at it ?

Comment: fwiw : using git 2.32 on linux, and trashing a repo by removing one single object file (the file wasn't part of a pack), I have no problem resetting to the commits right before and right after. What git version / OS are you running ?

Answer (score 0):

If the corrupted blob is part of only one single commit, you can "squelch" that commit using `git replace`, followed by `git filter-branch` :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* c66f110 (HEAD -> master) head commit
* 684f855 after
* b8e0882 -- corrupt commit --
* de068cf before
* 8cfa273
* 3ac9d71
...

# replace the corrupt commit with its parent :
$ git replace b8e0882 de068cf

$ git log --oneline --graph
* c66f110 (HEAD -> master) head commit
* 684f855 after
* b8e0882 (replaced) before
* 8cfa273
* 3ac9d71

# now run `git filter-branch --index-filter`, to turn the "temporary"
# replace into a permanent history rewriting :
$ git filter-branch --index-filter true -- --all
```

---

Here is a more manual but perhaps easier to understand workflow :

- create a new, empty repository next to your current one :

```
cd ..
git init cleanrepo   # you can add --bare to avoid problems with active branches
```

- add this repo as a remote to your current repo :

```
cd myrepo
git remote add cleanrepo ../cleanrepo
```

- push the last correct commit to that repo :

```
# choose a branch name, for example 'cleanbranch' :
git push cleanrepo <sha>:refs/heads/cleanbranch
```

If this works, `cleanrepo` should have no knowledge of that corrupted blob. You can push any other valid branch or commit to that cleanrepo.

---

*[update]* If it is still relevant, here is a way to manually graft the `after..master` ccommit on top of your rescue branch.

To illustrate, I will create two branches `rescue` and `graft` :

```
* c66f110 (HEAD -> master) head commit
* 684f855 (graft) after
* b8e0882 -- corrupt commit --
* de068cf (rescue) before
* 8cfa273
* 3ac9d71
...
```

and bring the commits coming after `graft` on top of `rescue`.

The starting point it to create, on top of `rescue`, a commit which has the exact same content as graft :

```
# starting from commit 'graft' :
git checkout graft
# use 'git reset --soft' to keep its content in the index, on top of 'rescue' :
git reset --soft rescue
# now commit ; you can use '-C' to copy the message from the original commit :
git commit -C 684f855
```

You can now rebase the remaining commits from `master` :

```
git rebase --onto graft 684f855 master
```

You should now have :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
* dd2e76c (HEAD -> master) head commit  # the hashes have been changed,
* cf176ad (graft) after                 # but the content is the same
* de068cf (rescue) before
* 8cfa273
* 3ac9d71
...
```

This rewritten `master` branch doesn't have the corrupt blob in its history anymore, you can safely push it to your cleanrepo.

Comment: @matt : that's perfectly valid :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did your second approach "partly" and it worked for me. Anyway, the git replace is interesting knowledge. Maybe I need it somewhere in the future. What I did: 1) Create new empty bare repo. 2) Branch from the commit priot to the corruption. 3) Push that new branch to the new empty repo. 4) Clone the new empty repo a second time and checkout the remote branch  -> Yes, the corrupted commit is not visible. Now there is no "master" branch. Everything looks good. 5) Rename that branch to "master".